# Check if a model has specific attributes, and if is found check if it has values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have 2 Django models, very similar:

```
class ImageUp(models.mode)l:

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload_to)
    additional_image_types = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class LogoUp(models.model):

    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload_to)
    additional_logo_types = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I retrieve instances of  the models from database and I want to do some image/logo manipulation, so I'm checking for attributes presence:

```
try:      
    additional = obj.getattr( f'additional_{attr_name}_types')
except AttributeError:
   .....
```

`attr_name`, I received as a parameter, and can be 'logo' or 'image', but I still do a check, in case wrong 'prefix' was sent
 `additional_..`, can be null, json empty or json with values

I receive 2 errors:

```
  object has no attribute 'getattr'
  getattr(): attribute name must be string # if I check type of `f string` is <str>
```

So, what I want is to know if  it is and `image` or `logo`, if `addtional..` has values

Comment: Your check is wrong: it should be `additional = getattr(obj, 'additional_{attr_name}_types')`. Also, did you forget to add `.format(attr_name=attr_name)`?

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle obviously not using python 3.6 and the magic new f-strings yet :-)

Comment: @Tobias  '.format', I'm using an f string, why should I need format ?

Comment: Sorry, forget that part of the comment, I wasn't familiar with f strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getattr` is not a method on an object; it's a built-in function. You need:

```
additional = getattr(obj, f'additional_{attr_name}_types')
```

(It is *implemented* via the `__getattr__` method, but you shouldn't call double-underscore methods directly.)

Comment: I changed but I still get the error on the f string "getattr(): attribute name must be string", if I use a normal string as a test it works

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Even if `attr_name` was something other than a string, the result of the f string would still be a string. Can you show the fuill traceback (as an edit to the question)?